# KML file polygon data to db/php?

Tags: maps, kml

I'm using gmaps v3 and I am using a kml file to display polygon shapes.

What I want to do, is that if I have a LNG/LAT coordinate, how to find whether it falls on the boundary or inside the shape?

I understand you can do this with V2 maps but not V3. So then my questions are:

Can I import the coordinates into my db in a useful way that I can then do a select statement if the LNG/LAT falls in between?

Can I do something useful on the serverside end since I have all the data to hand anyway?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I found a way of converting the kml file to lat/lng coordinates which I could then apply to a php function here: derivante.com/files/phpgis.txt

Comment: this link is dead